# Log into AD account through Command Line

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, login, windows-sbs-2003

Our SBS2003 server likes to lose connection every so often. This appears to 'kick' everyone out, so that no-one can access the server or its shared folders without a log off > log in. It usually brings up an error message stating that Windows 7 (on the client machines) cannot find the server, even though its ping-able.

Is there a way to login through the command line so I can just write a batch file and have the users double-click it and enter their credentials instead of closing down programs and logging out/in over and over?

Comment: Just a recommendation - but I think it would be better to solve your actual problem, then to implement a workaround like this.

Answer (score 0):

We had a problem like this on our PowerVault server, solution: monitor the interface for 24 hrs till we found what was causing it.. it turns out it was a remote backup job in Backup Exec, flooding the interface.. added a second NIC, set that for BEX, problem solved!

Your problem is probably something else, you might just have to stop and start the netlogon service.. I don't know. Any information you can give on the actual problem would help us to help you though.

btw, yes, you can login through a command line, however, it uses the same kerberos/ntlm auth as windows, so you won't be able to achieve what you may think you can. If there is a problem with the server, this still won't work. (and you need to drop ALL the connections to the server first, not just a single shared drive like below)

eg:

```
net use g: /delete
net use g: \\myserver\share /persistent:yes /user:DOMAIN\username p@ssw0rd
```

etc..